# JavaScript: Rotate an array to the left and then to the right by a given number of rotations

Tags: javascript, arrays, rotation

I need to be able to write a function that rotates a given array, first to the left, and then to the right by a given number of rotations.

What I have written so far:

```
function rotateArray(arr, rotLeft, rotRight) {
let len = arr.length;
for(let i=0; i<rotLeft; i++){ 
    let temp = arr[0];
    for(let i=0; i< len; i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[len-1]=temp;
}
return arr;

for(let i=0; i<rotRight; i++){ 
    let temp = arr[0];
    for(let i=0; i< len; i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[len-1]=temp;
}
return arr;
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

let rotLeft = 3;
let rotRight = 4;
let output = rotateArray(arr, rotLeft, rotRight);
console.log("New Array:", output);
```

Example of my code running:

Initial array = [1,2,3,4,5];
Resulted array = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3].

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.22.0/src/utils/array/RotateLeft.js is this usefull for you? or also https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.22.0/src/utils/array/RotateRight.js

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want:

```
const rotate = (array, rotLeft, rotRight) => {
    const leftPass = [...array.slice(rotLeft), ...array.slice(0, rotLeft)];
    const rightPass = [...leftPass.slice(array.length - rotRight), ...leftPass.slice(0, array.length - rotRight)];
    return rightPass
}

// rotate([1,2,3,4,5], 3, 4) = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have separate methods for `rotateLeft` and `rotateRight`.

On each left rotate, take first element and keep it at last (shift and push)
On each right rotate, take last element and keep it at first (pop and unshift)

```js
const rotateLeft = (arr, num) =>
  Array.from({ length: num }).forEach(() => arr.push(arr.shift()));
const rotateRight = (arr, num) =>
  Array.from({ length: num }).forEach(() => arr.unshift(arr.pop()));

const rotateArray = (arr, rotLeft, rotRight) => {
  rotateLeft(arr, rotLeft);
  rotateRight(arr, rotRight);
};

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let rotLeft = 3;
let rotRight = 4;

rotateArray(arr, rotLeft, rotRight);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong with your code:

> 1. The part of the code which should rotate to the right is same as the one which rotates to the left

In order to rotate the array to the right, you have to start from the end of the array (instead of the start, which is for left rotation):

```
for(let i = 0; i < rotRight; i++) { 
    let temp = arr[len - 1];
    for(let i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) { // start from the last index, end at 0
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[0] = temp;
}
```

---

> 2. You return the array (`arr`) just after finishing the left rotation,
>      therefore exiting the function before right rotation is executed.
>      All you need to do is remove the first occurrence of the line
>      `return arr;`

Here's the working code:

```js
function rotateArray(arr, rotLeft, rotRight) {
  let len = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < rotLeft; i++) {
    let temp = arr[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    arr[len - 1] = temp;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < rotRight; i++) {
    let temp = arr[len - 1];
    for (let i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) { // start from the last index, end at 0
      arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[0] = temp;
  }
  return arr;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let rotLeft = 3;
let rotRight = 4;
let output = rotateArray(arr, rotLeft, rotRight);
console.log("New Array:", output);
```